# Convert a Quartz Scheduler to unix cron scheduler

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

I have a quick question please, i should convert some Quartz Scheduler to unix machine cron.
The Quartz Scheduler is **0 30 11-18/22 * * ?** and when i put it in the site : http://www.cronmaker.com/ it shows me that the cron is running every 11h30 of every day. 
So for me 0 30 11-18/22 * * is equals to 0 30 11 * *  , is this correct ?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: the construction 11-18/22 is strange, it should mean: From 11 to 18h with step 22. Can you clarify when those jobs need to be executed

Comment: @RomeoNinov ,yes it is very strange this expression but it is accepted and run every day at 11:30

Answer (score 0):

For every day run at 11:30 you should rewrite the above Quartz Scheduler like:

```
30 11 * * * /path/to/the/job
```